# Name Validation in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a Input filed for name only. How can I validate that with alphabets only. Numbers will not be allowed in that.

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="from-input" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." v-model="name" />
<span v-if="this.name == ''">Enter a name</span>
<span v-else-if="this.nameValidation">Numbers not allowed</span>
</div>

data(){
  return {
     name: "",
  }
}

computed: {
  nameValidation(){
        if(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/.test(this.name)){
            return true
        }else{
            false
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simpler way is to use native input 'pattern' property.
but if you want to use the only Vue for this then you can use this

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   comp: {
      data() {
       return{
         input: '',
          error: ''
        }
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          <input type="text" @keyup="checkValue" v-model="input" />
          <div v-if="error" class="alert">{{ error }}</div>
        </div>
      `,
      methods: {
       checkValue(){
           if(/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(this.input)) {
             this.error = 'Input value contains other syantax.'; 
           }else{
              this.error = '';
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}

.alert{
      padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff72728a;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #d48888;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp></comp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the HTML5 pattern property.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="from-input"
  placeholder="Enter Your Name..."
  v-model="name" 
  pattern="[A-Za-z]+"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the costume validation method of Vue to validate Name Filed.
Please the read the official Vue documentation in which they explain with example.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html